# Load resource assets in a dynamic framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I was able to create a dynamic framework with assets/resources/bundle in it. I added the dynamic framework simply by drag-drop inside my Xcode project. My problem is that how can I load the resources programmatically? Looks like resources are not copied in the main bundle application. Here is my framework structure:

```
MyFramework.framework/
   MyFramework  -> Versions/Current/MyFramework
   Resources    -> Versions/Current/Resources
   Versions/
      A/
         MyFramework
         Headers/
            MyHeader.h
         Resources/
            MyFramework.bundle
      Current  -> A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `NSBundle(forClass: MyFrameworkClass.classForCoder())`

Comment: this returns the main application's bundle, however, upon trying to access the MyFramework.bundle it returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by creating an embedded framework instead. Here is my new folder structure

```
   MyFramework.framework/
   MyFramework  -> Versions/Current/MyFramework
   Resources    -> Versions/Current/Resources
   Versions/
      A/
         MyFramework
         Headers/
            MyHeader.h
         Resources/
            MyFramework.bundle
      Current  -> A
   Resources/
      MyFramework.bundle -> Versions/A/Resources/MyFramework.bundle
```

In Resources folder is a symbolic link to the real resource bundle. I simply drag-and-drop it to my Xcode project.